# Can a content entity type have a bundle which is a configuration entity type as with the contact form?

Tags: 8

What is `bundle_entity_type` for `@ContentEntityType` when `id = contact_message` and where `contact_message` is `@ConfigEntityType?`
Can a configuration entity Type be a bundle of a content entity type?

core/modules/contact/src/Entity/Message.php

```
/**
 * Defines the contact message entity.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "contact_message",
 *   label = @Translation("Contact message"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Contact messages"),
 *   label_singular = @Translation("contact message"),
 *   label_plural = @Translation("contact messages"),
 *   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
 *     singular = "@count contact message",
 *     plural = "@count contact messages",
 *   ),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Contact form"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "access" = "Drupal\contact\ContactMessageAccessControlHandler",
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityNullStorage",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\contact\MessageViewBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\contact\MessageForm"
 *     }
 *   },
 *   admin_permission = "administer contact forms",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "bundle" = "contact_form",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode"
 *   },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "contact_form",
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity.contact_form.edit_form",
 * )
 */
class Message extends ContentEntityBase implements MessageInterface {
```

core/modules/contact/src/Entity/ContactForm.php
which says `bundle_of` ==> `contact_message`

```
/**
 * Defines the contact form entity.
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "contact_form",
 *   label = @Translation("Contact form"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Contact forms"),
 *   label_singular = @Translation("contact form"),
 *   label_plural = @Translation("contact forms"),
 *   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
 *     singular = "@count contact form",
 *     plural = "@count contact forms",
 *   ),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "access" = "Drupal\contact\ContactFormAccessControlHandler",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\contact\ContactFormListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\contact\ContactFormEditForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\contact\ContactFormEditForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDeleteForm"
 *     }
 *   },
 *   config_prefix = "form",
 *   admin_permission = "administer contact forms",
 *   bundle_of = "contact_message",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "label"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/contact/manage/{contact_form}/delete",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/contact/manage/{contact_form}",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/contact",
 *     "canonical" = "/contact/{contact_form}",
 *   },
 *   config_export = {
 *     "id",
 *     "label",
 *     "recipients",
 *     "reply",
 *     "weight",
 *     "message",
 *     "redirect",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ContactForm extends ConfigEntityBundleBase implements ContactFormInterface {
```

Comment: The Contact module uses a mockup content entity type with no storage and a bundle config entity to configure fields for forms. So the resulting front end contact form is technically the same as a back end node add form.

Answer (score 1):

This may be easier to understand with Nodes, since Nodes have been used by almost every Drupal site builder.

Nodes are a Content Entity. Nodes have bundles (aka content types). For example, a blog. Now, to define the blog type, a new Config Entity is created - the Node Type entity. Config entities have keys. The key for the blog Node type is 'blog'. This key identifies the node type. But the blog bundle is still a Node entity, and therefore is a Content Entity.

The contact form works the same way.

So to answer your question, no, bundles of Content entities cannot be config entities, as bundles are just a subset of the original entity, which is a Content entity. But a Config entity is used to define the bundle (allowing the types to be exported as configuration).

You could almost compare it to the 'type' field on a Content Entity being an Entity Reference to a Config entity that defines the type.

Comment: Thanks for replying but in the contact , you can see that ConfigEntityType contact_form is a bundle of ContentEntityType contact_message whereas a Node node  which is ContentEntityType is a bundle of ConfigEntityType node_type ?
So here node is a bundle of entity type which is a configentity similarly for Contact ?

Comment: No. Nodes are not bundles. They are Content Entities. Nodes have bundles, they cannot be bundles.

Comment: As per your answer, you are saying that Content Entities can only have bundles which will be Content Entities whereas Config Entities can have bundles which can be either Content Entity or Config Entity? is that correct ?

Comment: The bundles are sub-types of an Entity. A blog bundle IS a node. So it cannot become a config entity.

Comment: So when it says in NodeType.php ==> ConfigEntityType id="node_type"  and bundle_of = "node" whereas in Node.php ==> ContentEntityType id="node" and bundle_entity_type=node_type ?
can you elaborate on this so I can understand it completely, thanks again !!!

Comment: You have two entity types: `node` and `node_type`. For each bundle of Node in the system, there will be a `node_type` entity, defining that bundle (eg. blog). When you create a new blog on your system, you create a new entity of type `node`. If you create another entity of type `node`. You create as many of these as you want, and there will still be only the one `node_type` entity that defines the blog type.